# Where to host the docs/html files of a private project using Azure

Tags: html, azure, azure-functions, hosting, private

How can I host & deploy the docs (html files) of a private python project on Sourcetree using  Azure. I expect few people to use the documentation files (not everyone should see the files, it needs to protected) . What is the best way to deploy & host the documentation files of a private project using Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on what you mean by "private".  If all the hosts that need to connect to this repo of HTML docs is in Azure, the answer is put them all in Blob Storage [configured for static websites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website-host) and restrict access to a Vnet.

If you need to restrict users coming in from the Internet then you will need to host your files in an Azure Web App and follow the instructions on [restricting IP access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions).

The two options above were Network based restrictions.  If you need to restrict access by users then you will need to look at authentication for your application.  Azure Web Apps support [authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scenario-secure-app-authentication-app-service) via Azure Active Directory and other 3rd party providers.

**Note:** this option will allow anyone with an account in your Azure AD to get access to the files.  If you need to restrict to a specific group or users you need to configure further.  Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-restrict-your-app-to-a-set-of-users

Comment: Thank you for your answer, indeed Blob storage seems alright for my use case. thanks